# IOS image picker in navigation view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to browse an image and display in `imageview` using `UIImagePickerController`. Basically the view I am using to browse the image is based on `navigationController`.

But using the below code after I select the image and come back to view, I can see that the view is flickering to left right and the image is not showing in image view.

Actually the entire source code is quit long, thats why I post the image picker part only. If required I can post more code.

**RegistrationFormViewController.h**

```
@interface RegistrationFormViewController : ViewController
<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageUser;

- (IBAction)registerBt:(id)sender;
```

**RegistrationFormViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _barButtonBack.target = self.revealViewController;
    _barButtonBack.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];


    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.imageUser setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self.imageUser addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
}



-(void)tapDetected{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark - ImagePickerController Delegate

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    // Dismiss the image selection, hide the picker and

    //show the image view with the picked image

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.imageUser setImage:image];

     self.imageUser.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why do you update `self.imageUser.contentMode` in the `didFinishPickingImage` callback?

Comment: Actually I am quiet new to ios, did that causing the problem, I have commented that section, but still the behavior is same.

Comment: At least update content mode first, then set the image, then dismiss the picker at last.

Comment: if you get the image or not? if you used AVAsset you will get original image but size to be reduced

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your code that you showed here. However try this in didFinishPickingImage -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.imageUser.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
     [self.imageUser setImage:image];

    });
```

and move this code to viewDidLoad

```
imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

you can also check whether you are getting the image or not using breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

In viewcontroller.m file, just put this code:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)(ALAsset *asset);
typedef void (^ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)(NSError *error);
- (IBAction)Gallery:(id)sender {

self.ImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
self.ImagePickerController.delegate = self;
self.ImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:self.ImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)Camera:(id)sender {

    self.ImagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
    self.ImagePickerController.delegate = self;
    self.ImagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentViewController:self.ImagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];


    NSURL *imageUrl  = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock resultblock = ^(ALAsset *myasset)
    {
        ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [myasset defaultRepresentation];
        CGImageRef resolutionRef = [representation fullResolutionImage];

        if (resolutionRef) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resolutionRef scale:1.0f orientation:(UIImageOrientation)representation.orientation];
            self.SelectedImage.image =image;

        }
    };
    ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock failureblock  = ^(NSError *myerror)
    {
        NSLog(@"cant get image - %@",[myerror localizedDescription]);
    };

    if(imageUrl)
    {
        ALAssetsLibrary* assetslibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc]init];
        [assetslibrary assetForURL:imageUrl resultBlock:resultblock failureBlock:failureblock];
    }

}
```

In viewcontroller.h file

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic)UIImagePickerController *ImagePickerController;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *SelectedImage;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this delegate method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

     UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
     [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```